# PAC PowerPlatformCLI

Tags: pac

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'bolt.cli, Version=1.27.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at bolt.Program.d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
at bolt.Program.Main()
at bolt.Program.()

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, updating to the latest version